# sed/awk: extract one number from string

Tags: sed, awk

I have many lines like the following being returned from a bash command, with different `sourceNodeIds` of varying digit lengths:

```
<NodeAssociation sourceNodeId="33654" [...] sourceNodeEntity="Issue" />
```

I'd like to pipe it to sed or awk and just return the number nnnn from `sourceNodeId="nnnn"`

something like:

```
cat blah | sed 's/.+?sourceNodeId="\(\d+\)".+/\1/'
```

but this isn't working. I'm on a Mac if that makes any difference (I think the version of sed may be different). I know Perl regexes, but I think sed is expecting a different kind.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You might consider moving this to stackoverflow, I'm sure we'll be able to help but they might be quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` doesn't know about `\d` and non-greedy matches. You don't need to use `cat`. This should work:

```
sed 's/.*sourceNodeId="\([0-9]\+\)".*/\1/' file
```

Some `sed` versions are picky about wanting a `-e` (it will work even if it's not required):

```
sed -e 's/.*sourceNodeId="\([0-9]\+\)".*/\1/' file
```

If your `sed` supports `-r` you can skip the escaping:

```
sed -er 's/.*sourceNodeId="([0-9]+)".*/\1/' file
```

Comment: thanks! I couldn't get it to work on mac, but it's great on linux. I'm piping from other input, hence the cat. I did have to just use sed -r though.

Comment: On OS X, use `-E` instead of `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, works:

```
cat blah | cut -f2 -d\"
```